# How to clear Calendar Date Picker Selected Values in UWP, C#

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a data-grid control and a series of controls that filter data in that data grid.

Those controls can be grouped into two as follows.

- Filter Combo Box (which contains `Today`, `Yesterday`, `Last Week`, `Last Month`)
- Two Calendar Date Picker and a button (which are `From` and `To`, when I clicked the button, the event takes values of those `From` and `To` date values and do the work)

Now, I want to do some UX works as follows.

- When the selected item of Filter Combo Box is changed, the values of two calendar date picker are cleared.
- When the button is clicked, the selected item of Filter Combo Box is cleared and set back to its original placeholder text.

I can manage it works for requirement 2 but 1 is not going well. Below is my event handlers. I'm not using MVVM. Just with code-behind.

```
private void SelectionChanged_Filter(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    /*DatePicker_FromDate.ClearValue(CalendarDatePicker.DateProperty);
      DatePicker_FromDate.PlaceholderText = "Pick a Date";
      DatePicker_ToDate.ClearValue(CalendarDatePicker.DateProperty);
      DatePicker_ToDate.PlaceholderText = "Pick a Date";*/

      DatePicker_FromDate.Date = null
      DatePicker_ToDate.Date = null;
}
```

```
 private void ButtonClick_Filter(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
      // Clear the Filter Combobox's selected value
      ComboBox_Filter.SelectedIndex = -1;

      // EXCEPTION is in the below line:
      var fromDate = Convert.ToDateTime(DatePicker_FromDate.Date.ToString()).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
      var toDate = Convert.ToDateTime(DatePicker_ToDate.Date.ToString()).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");

      //...
}
```

The EXCEPTION is :

```
System.FormatException: 'String '' was not recognized as a valid DateTime.'
```

I think setting `null` to date value of the calendar date picker is invalid. How can I clear those values when I changed the combobox?

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**
For clearing the value of CalendarDatePicker, you could set Date property to null like following.

```
DatePicker_FromDate.Date = null;
DatePicker_ToDate.Date= null;
```

For pass the value,first you could judge whether it is null then operate its value.

```
string toDate= = DatePicker_ToDate.Date == null ? "" : DatePicker_ToDate.Date.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Comment: `SelectedDate` property is not showing up.

Comment: The one I used is in this namespace: `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls`.

Comment: I'm using `Calendar Date Picker` not Date Picker.

Comment: I'm so sorry. I have updated my answer, please check it.

Comment: When the Date of CalendarDatePicker is null, you also could use another string instead of  `""`, such as `string toDate= = DatePicker_ToDate.Date == null ? "00/00/0000" : DatePicker_ToDate.Date.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");`

Answer (score 1):

If you are setting the `Date` property to `null`, the `string` will be `null` as well: using the following code that uses the safe-navigation operator (`?.`):

```
var fromDate = DatePicker_FromDate.Date?.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
var toDate = DatePicker_ToDate.Date?.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

I guess this is what you want.

Also note that it's pointless to first convert a `DateTime` to a `string` just to convert it back to a `DateTime` and then convert it to a `string` again...